# Armazenar todas as posições do array em uma variável?

Tags: php, array

Eu possuo um array que contém 3 posições, cada uma delas armazena um texto longo, como posso fazer para armazenar em uma única variável todas essas 3 posições do array?. por exemplo:

Array['Gol','Pálio','Celta']

$TodasAsMarcas = //Todas as posições do array acima.

Infelizmente não consigo pois meu código sobrescreve até a ultima posição, então as posições anteriores ficam perdidas.

Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Tentou como [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) ? ele vai transforma todos os elementos do array em uma string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), transforma um array em uma string, a função aceita dois argumentos o primeiro é o delimitador o qual sepera os itens do array, o segundo é o array. Se for informado apenas um argumento(array) a string de saída será toda colada.

```
<?php
$arr = Array('Gol','Pálio','Celta', 'Audi A3');
echo $str = implode('#', $arr);
echo $str = implode($arr);
```

Saída:

```
Gol#Pálio#Celta#Audi A3
GolPálioCeltaAudi A3
```

Para fazer o processo oposto utilize a função [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).